# Script to append file with new results - sequence expected error

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have wrote a python script that is supposed to use a regex on an existing column then write this to a new csv file.

The CSV has 6 columns, ID, book, author, category, keywords, rule.

The keywords column is actually the exact same as the rule column, however i want to update the keywords column with the output of my REGEX in my code.

I seem to be getting an **_csv.Error: sequence expected error**, script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env

import csv
import re

file1 = open('test.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=';')
your_list = list(reader)
new_rows_list = []


for i in your_list:
    x = re.search(r"\"value\":(.*?)\,\"", i[5])
    new_rows_list.append(x)
file1.close()

file2 = open('test.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(file2)
writer.writerows(new_rows_list)
file2.close()
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to give an example of `test.csv` ? It would then be possible to recreate your problem.

Comment: explained the csv

Comment: Your explanation of the CSV shows commas separating each column, but your code is using `;` ?

Comment: Make sure that the CSV file does not contain any empty lines (including the last line).

Comment: Hi Martin, its actually using ";" to seperate them

Comment: The input is supposed to just be the file itself, generated from a SQL query I run. When the script reads the file it is supposed to manipulate the 5th column, strip most of the content from the original text then replace the original by writing the results of the regex

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one

```
import re
import csv

file1 = open('test.csv', 'r')
# using comma separete 
reader = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')

lst_values = []

for idx, i in enumerate(reader):

    x = re.search(r"\"value\":(.*?)\,\"", i[5])
    # Add the result of regexp to keyword column
    try:
      i[4] += x.group(0) 
    except AttributeError:
      None

    lst_values.append(i)


wr_file = open('test.csv', 'w')
for record in lst_values:  

  wr_file.write(str(record))

wr_file.close()
```

Comment: Seeing this error:     __import__(pkg)
  File "GDPR_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    x = re.search(r"\"value\":(.*?)\,\"", i[5])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Did you change the "," to ";" ??